# Excel formula over full column result is different than with fixed range (same values)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so this is what I'm trying to do:

[image: Excel image]

You can see B1 formula in B2 and C1 formula in C2.

I'm applying the formulas with ctrl+shift+enter, thats why there is "{ }" around the formulas.

The correct value is from C1, as it can be seen if you place this on Google:
**10^0.5 + 10^0.6 + 10^0.7**

I have no idea why this is happening!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the whole column it is including all the blanks as `0`

```
10^(0/10) = 1
```

[image]

So it is adding 1 for each row that is blank, that is 1048573 rows or `1048573+12.1552217`

---

One should not use full column references when using array formulas.

You can limit the range with this array formula and still be dynamic

```
=SUM(10^($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))/10))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Now you can add to the list without changing the formula and only iterate through the data without extra iterations.

[image]

---

You can remove the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter with SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(10^($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))/10))
```

It still has the need to limit the data range to only the data to limit the iterations, but can be entered normally.

---

If you really want to do the extra iterations you will need to put an IF in you SUM:

```
=SUM(IF(A:A<>"",10^(A:A/10)))
```

or with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")*(10^(A:A/10)))
```

These will be slower as they are doing nearly 2 million calculations, 99.9% of which are unneeded.

Comment: Yep, your formula worked! Thank you very much for the help. The only thing that I had to change was the **,** separating function elements to **;** not sure why. So in the end it was like **=SUM(10^($A$1:INDEX(A:A;MATCH(1E+99;A:A))/10))**

Comment: @GuiFGDeo please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  The use of `,` vs. `;` is a local setting.  EN-US uses `,`  While other parts of the world use `;`.

Comment: Thanks for the last piece of explanation :) I've already marked as answered! Thanks!

Comment: If possible, just to be 100% sure, could you also explain what this will do: **INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))**. Excel definition of INDEX and MATCH makes me a little confused.

Comment: It finds and sets the last cell in column A that has a number.  So it is now dynamic as numbers are added or removed from the column the formula adjusts to iterate only those between A1 and the last cell with a number.